# python error AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute 'ArugmentParser'

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import json
import requests

parser = argparse.ArugmentParser()
parser.add_argument('-k', '--key', required='True')
```

Comment: Change `Arugment` to `Argument`

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo in `ArgumentParser()`:

```
import argparse
import json
import requests

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-k', '--key', required='True')
```

Comment: Thank you all.. it is a typo... 
Thank you for helping out..

Answer (score 2):

Because it is "argparse.ArgumentParser()" but you wrote "argparse.ArugmentParser()"

Comment: Thank you all.. it is a typo... 
Thank you for helping out..

Answer (score 0):

> `parser = argparse.ArugmentParser()`

That's not how you spell 'Argument'.

Use
`parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`

Comment: Thank you all.. it is a typo... 
Thank you for helping out..